# Trying to set the marker on the current position gives me nullpointer exception

Tags: android, button, background-color

I have done the following things in my program:

1. I am generating some `Buttons` programmatically in my `MenuItemsActivity` class. I have a  `Listview` in the `xml` of the `MenuItemsActivity` class.
2. When I click on the button the appropriate contents get loaded in the `Listview`. I just refresh the activity i.e I am using the same Listview to load different contents based on the button which is clicked.

I want to do the following:

1. When the Button is clicked I want to change the background  of the button to 'blue_tab` and maintain that same color when the same activity reloads. Can anyone guide me step by step what to do, as I am a newbie to Android.

   ```
     i = getIntent();
   String Salad=i.getStringExtra("Salad");
   String cat_name_from_fragment=i.getStringExtra("category name");
   final ListView salad_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.salads);

   category = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
   items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
   db = new DbHelper(MenuItemsActivity.this);
   category.clear();
   if (i.getStringExtra("category name") != null) {
       String getcategory = i.getStringExtra("category name").toString();
       items = db.retrieve_item_details(getcategory);
       Log.i("sub items", "" + items);
   }
   else if(cat_name_from_fragment!=null)
   {
       items = db.retrieve_item_details(cat_name_from_fragment);   
   }
   else
   {
       items = db.retrieve_item_details("Salads");
   }
   category = db.retrieve_category_name();


   count = category.size();
   Log.i("Sqlite database values", "" + count + " " + category);
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
       StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
               .permitAll().build();

       StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
   }

   LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);
   int i = 0;
   for (HashMap<String, String> map : category)

       for (Entry<String, String> mapEntry : map.entrySet()) {

           String key = mapEntry.getKey();
           String value = mapEntry.getValue();
           TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
           tv2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(40, 90));
           Log.i("map", "" + value);
           final Button tv1 = new Button(this);
           tv1.setId(i);
           tv1.setText(value);
           tv1.setTextSize(35);

           tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#1569C7"));
           tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
           tv1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.popup));
           tv1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300,90));
           tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   String text = tv1.getText().toString();
                   Log.e("text message", "" + text);
                   tv1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_tab));
                   Toast.makeText(MenuItemsActivity.this, "clicked", 1000)
                           .show();
                   Intent i = new Intent(MenuItemsActivity.this,
                           MenuItemsActivity.class);
                   i.putExtra("category name", "" + text);
                   finish();
                   startActivity(i);
               }
           });
           /*TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);

           tv2.setText("      ");
           tv2.setTextSize(10);

           tv2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);*/
           l1.addView(tv1);
           l1.addView(tv2);

           i++;
           Log.e("i count ", "" + i);
       }
   final int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.leftbar_logo ,R.drawable.leftbar_logo};


   ListAdapter k = new SimpleAdapter(MenuItemsActivity.this, items,
           R.layout.menulist, new String[] { "Item_Name", "Desc",
                   "Currency", "Price","url","veggie","cat" }, new int[] { R.id.cat_name,
                   R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3,R.id.url,R.id.veggie,R.id.Category}) {

       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           final View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

           final ImageView im=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
           TextView url=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.url);

           TextView veg=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.veggie);
           String vegg=veg.getText().toString();

           ImageView imagevegs=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.veggies);
           Log.i("veggie",""+vegg);
           if(vegg.compareToIgnoreCase("Veg")==0)
           {


               imagevegs.setImageResource(R.drawable.veg);
               imagevegs.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
           }
           else
           {imagevegs.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
               imagevegs.setImageResource(R.drawable.non);
           }

           final String urls="http://166.62.17.208/"+url.getText().toString();
           Log.i("urls",""+urls);

           imageLoader.DisplayImage(urls,im);
           //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
           return v;
       }

   };
   salad_list.setAdapter(k);
   ```

Comment: Ann, what problem you getting exactly? Still its unclear.

Comment: I want to change the background of the button from `popup` to `blue_tab` when the button is clicked and want to maintain the blue_tab background after my activity refreshes i.e even `Intent i = new Intent(MenuItemsActivity.this,MenuItemsActivity.class);` occurs I want the button to maintain blue_tab background.

Comment: So its nt changing your background right now? as code is fine I think

Comment: First of all, don't reload the same Activity again and again, just refresh the Listview with the new records fetched according to the filter you have applied. Second use the selector for different button states. Hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: ya, dnt call your whole activity, just refresh your ListView only

Comment: The background gets changed for a while to blue_tab but after the startactivity(i) executes the color comes back to popup

Comment: can you send me your whole project? let me check it.

Comment: I will post the whole code here

Comment: please check the full code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57734/discussion-between-pratik-and-ann).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PreferenceManager` to save data and use it when the app is reloaded/restarted

**sample:**

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text = tv1.getText().toString();
            Log.e("text message", "" + text);
            if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MenuItemsActivity.this).getString("button", "").length != 0)
                tv1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_tab));
            else
            {
                Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MenuItemsActivity.this).edit();
                editor.putString("button", "1");
                editor.commit(); 
                tv1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_tab)); 
            }
            Toast.makeText(MenuItemsActivity.this, "clicked", 1000)
                    .show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MenuItemsActivity.this,
                    MenuItemsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("category name", "" + text);
            finish();
            startActivity(i);
        }
```